# How to change the M2_REPO of Maven in windows

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Currently,I have to change device(laptop) for working ---> I have to change the environment to be suitbale with my Project.

However, I got an issue relating to setting the M2_REPO home.

At first, M2_REPO is being set default to a local in C such as the below :
[image]

However, I want to change M2_REPOT to other local such as :
[image]

I set M2_REPO in the environment but they still don't work as well.

Please tell me know to config them ( Supposing I am using Eclipse for our project)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh.
Simplest soltion here :
Check the following screen to check if you have the good settings, to go here just go to window->preference and type maven in the type filter 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to restart Eclipse once you modify the M2_REPO variable? I think that JVM just reads all environment variables and then just keeps them in memory.

Are you sure you have set it up properly -> once you set it try to print it in the **new** command window with the following command: echo %M2_REPO%

Comment: I tried as your suggestion but the result doesn't look good :(